# How consider NULL as the MAX date instead of ignoring it in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I have a table to control user access to specific systems. The column "end_date" defines the limit date of those access. For example:

[image]

If "end_date" is NULL it means that users can have life time access. Considering this, when I make a query to get the max(end_date), how can I consider NULL as the max end_date ?

```html
SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM user_access WHERE user_id='80076'
```

I tried this but it didn't work...

Comment: why not  add 9999-01-01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'infinity'`, per [Datetimes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) 8.5.1.4. Special Values 'infinity     date, timestamp     later than all other time stamps'.

If for some reason you want to leave the data as is then:

```
SELECT MAX(coalesce(end_date, 'infinity')) FROM user_access WHERE user_id='80076';
```

This will substitute 'infinity' for `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess around with substituting in magic values, [I have implemented](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_strict_min_and_max) "strict" min and max functions which return NULL for any NULL input.

They are polymorphic, and so (I think) they support every type which defines ordering operations.